# Will this thermostat work for my wiring?

Tags: thermostat, heater

Here is the wiring from the existing thermostat:

[image]

The new thermostat is a Wyze.

[image: see wiring here]

Will this Wyze work with the existing wires?  Any help here on how?
If this unit won't work for me, what keywords can I use when shopping to ensure a thermostat will work with my system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That thermostat will not work. The terminal labels and type indicate small gauge *low voltage* wiring. You have line-level (high voltage) wiring. Look for a "line voltage" thermostat.